# Workflow: Copy document - history in TARGET library

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have a scenario whereby documents are initially created and edited in a "drafts" document library, but I want to "publish" approved major versions to a separate read-only library.  This last library should serve as the master list of the documents, including the master history of the major revisions.

The read-only library has versioning on.

However, when I use the Sharepoint Designer workflow action "copy list item", and trigger it on a document that was published once already, then there seem to be only two possibilities:
  -  If "overwrite" is "Yes" the copy list item completely replaces the existing document in the read-only library (including all history),
  - If "overwrite" is "No" a new document with an additional date/time stamp is created.

Ideally any copy of an item that "overwrites" a previous file should push the version down for that document in the target library.
Is this possible at all using just Sharepoint Designer?